# Issue in displaying Dropdown Menu on top of the webpage

Tags: html, css

I have a drop down menu that i want to show at the top of the Div but it is getting displayed down .Here is the Fiddle Link
[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/ga9k0ygj/) and here is the CSS used ..

```
.headerMenu
{
 width:100%;
 margin-left:182px;
}
```

Please help me to resolve this ..

Comment: @AndyHolmes I want the drop down to display beside the logo at the top ..Please see the fiddle

Comment: Check Now [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/ga9k0ygj/1/). You need to write beside the logo section.

Comment: @HansalMehta the questions are...why is that `select` on that bottom `div`? Why can't you simply put it next to the "logo"? You have it on the wrong place. Are you serious?

Comment: @RohanLopes Please see the Link http://jsfiddle.net/ga9k0ygj/3/ Why is the logo coming at the right side of the buttons?

Comment: This is because you have given the `float:left` property to buttons so they shifted to left first. If u want to display the logo on left side then add `img{float:left;}` to stylesheet.

Comment: @RohanLopes Ok I got it ..Removed that from the CSS but now the buttons are coming a little down to the top of the page ..http://jsfiddle.net/ga9k0ygj/4/  Fiddle..How to remove this ..This is last issue sir ..Please relpy

Comment: @HansalMehta What you want to say?

Comment: @RohanLopes In the fiddle link http://jsfiddle.net/ga9k0ygj/4/ Buttons like Front Desk,Restaurents are getting displayed a little down to the Logo image ..How to show the buttons from the top most part of the page like the logo image ?

Comment: @RohanLopes Can you please tell me why this is happening ?

Comment: @HansalMehta are you want to show buttons same alignment as logo image?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/63767/discussion-between-hansal-mehta-and-rohan-lopes).

Answer (score 0):

```
<div id="verticalDiv" class="verticalDiv">
<img src="img/hotelAwadh.png" alt="logo" style="float:left"/>
<div id="headerMenu" class="headerMenu">
    <select name="menu" style="font-family:'Courier New';color:#ffffff;background-color:#ff8900;font-weight:bold;font-size:14pt;">
        <option value="http://www.ricocheting.com/">Front Desk</option>
        <option value="http://www.google.com/">Google</option>
    </select>
</div>
<label name="roomOperation" id="roomOperation" style="font-style:normal; font-size:15px;font-weight:bold;"> Room Operation </label>
<ul id="quicklinks" class="quicklinks">
    <li><a href="#" rel="Document1" title="">Check in List</a></li>
    <li><a href="#" rel="Document2" title="">Check out List</a></li>
</ul>
```

Answer (score 0):

Remove the floats on your buttons, that's what makes them position to the left of the logo.

[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/ga9k0ygj/5/)

I removed the button style attribute from your html and added this to your css:

```
.verticalDiv button {
    margin-left:15px;
}
```